# PHP: Check if $_POST-Array contains empty/not set values?

Tags: php, http-post

Imagine a `$_POST-Array` from a form different input-types/elements. I want to iterate over the Array and check if the user has filled out all fields or chose an non-default option from all select-dropdowns.

In the code below I tried with the function `postContainsEmptyValues()`, but this does not work for the select fields (Edit: It works for the text-inputs).

How do I have to change the code?

(EDIT: updated the code according to brombeers hint (removing disabled))

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["btSubmit"])) {
  if (postContainsEmptyValues()) {
    echo "empty form element detected";
  } else {
    echo "all form-fields have been filled";
  }
}
function postContainsEmptyValues()
{
  $emptyElementDetected = false;
  foreach ($_POST as $element) {
    if ($element == "" || !isset($element)) {
      $emptyElementDetected = true;
    }
    return $emptyElementDetected;
  }
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; ?>" method="POST">
    <select name="selectBox1">
        <option value="" selected>-- choose one --</option>
        <option value="a">choose a</option>
        <option value="b">choose b</option>
    </select>
    <select name="selectBox2">
        <option value="" selected>-- choose one --</option>
        <option value="x">choose x</option>
        <option value="y">choose y</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="tfText" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="btSubmit">
</form>
```

Comment: The way you named your function, `if (!postContainsEmptyValues())` should be `if (postContainsEmptyValues())`: _if_ post contains empty elements, then echo "empty form element detected"

Comment: Thanks, my failure, but still it does not work. Edited the code in the original post.

Comment: Your code is missing a closing bracket `}`. Good code indentation would help.

Comment: Oops, yes, thanks. Added it. I typed the example just by hand without trying it. I think the problem is the part `if ($element == "" || !isset($element))` which does not evaluate the select-field.

Comment: _Don't_ type code here, copy/paste your original code. There might be typos in your original code that don't get transferred here because you typed it

Comment: _"I typed the example just by hand without trying it"_ - Then how can you say that it doesn't work? If you have some issue with some code, you need to post a copy of _that exact_ code without rewrites.

Comment: Have you tried a `var_dump($_POST)` to see if those empty `<select>`s get submitted? (Hint: `disabled` options won't be sent)

Comment: Btw, `!isset($element)` is probably not needed since we know that it's defined and empty form elements are empty strings, not `null`.

Comment: You are right, should try the code before, sorry. Original code is big, wanted to make it short. Just tried it the version above is running without typos.

Comment: Tried the `var_dump($_POST)`; the empty selects are just not existing, therefore I tried with the `isset`. (vardump-output missing selectBox2  because it hasn't been changed: `array(3) { ["selectBox1"]=> string(1) "a" ["tfText"]=> string(4) "asdf" ["btSubmit"]=> string(6) "Senden" }`

Comment: Options that are disabled won't be submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabled form elements/options won't be sent when submitting the form. Remove the `disabled` attribute from your `<option>`s:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="POST">
  <select name="selectBox1">
    <option value="" selected>-- choose one --</option>
    <option value="a">choose a</option>
    <option value="b">choose b</option>
  </select>
  <select name="selectBox2">
    <option value="" selected>-- choose one --</option>
    <option value="x">choose x</option>
    <option value="y">choose y</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="tfText" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="btSubmit">
</form>
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled: "*The Boolean disabled attribute, when present, makes the element not mutable, focusable, or even submitted with the form.*"

Edit: you're returning *inside* the `foreach` loop, so only the first item will be checked. Move the `return` outside of the loop. Complete working code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btSubmit'])) { 
    if (postContainsEmptyValues()) {
        echo "empty form element detected";
    }
}

function postContainsEmptyValues()
{
    $emptyElementDetected = false;
    foreach ($_POST as $element) {
        if ($element == "" || !isset($element)) {
           $emptyElementDetected = true;
        }
    }
    return $emptyElementDetected;
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="POST">
  <select name="selectBox1">
    <option value="" selected>-- choose one --</option>
    <option value="a">choose a</option>
    <option value="b">choose b</option>
  </select>
  <select name="selectBox2">
    <option value="" selected>-- choose one --</option>
    <option value="x">choose x</option>
    <option value="y">choose y</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="tfText" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="btSubmit">
</form>
```

A slightly shorter/more performant version of your function (this returns right away when an empty element has been found, no need to check *all* elements):

```
function postContainsEmptyValues()
{
    foreach ($_POST as $element) {
        if (empty($element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but still it doesn't work. Removing the disabled and then var_dumping it I get for the not changed select-Boxes `["selectBox2"]=>string(0) ""`

Comment: @BNetz Edited my answer, your `return` exited the `foreach` before it could check all elements

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `true` if there's a missing element, but you are echoing `empty element found` if the function return `false`

Comment: Thanks, indeed, but still it does not work. Edited the code in the original post.